# Row: a RenderFlex overflowed on the right

Tags: flutter

I get the error when using the following widget

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 3.0 pixels on the right.

```
body: Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
              height: 60.0,
            ),
            Text(
              'Flash Chat',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 35.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
),
```

I tried to wrap the row with an Expanded but seems it doesn work. What can we do here except of reducing the size of the text?

[image]

Comment: is the row inside a fixed width widget ?

Comment: include the parents of the row as well

Comment: @Henok included

Comment: try wrapping your column with IntrinsicWidth widget

Comment: Try use FittedBox

Comment: you can reduce the horizontal padding alongside using `FittedBox`

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the FontWeight to `fontWeight: FontWeight.w700.` Not only 700 but try out values 100,200,300, etc. whatever fits.